# How can I add an observable to my template form for Onepage Checkout?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, knockoutjs

I am trying to add a checkbox to the checkout page in Magento2, but I am having issues with it. I have worked through http://devdocs.Magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html and successfully add a checkout form with a button, which works all well and good. I am able to bind an element to a function, but I need to bind a checkbox to an observable.

Now, I have read a I need an observable because when I try to click the checkbox, it remains empty. I don't know how to do that and am looking for some assistance.

I have seen in other questions code similar to:

```
var viewModel = {
    setInstoreShipping: ko.observable(false)
};

viewModel.setInstoreShipping.subscribe(function (newState) {
    if (newState) {
        alert("Checked!");
    } else {
        alert("Unchecked!");
    }
});
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

but when applying this, I receive an error:
`You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element`. So my question is, how do I bind a checkbox to an observable and how do I create the observable to bind to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because checkout page already do knockout binding when it is rendered. You need to create an UI component and work with that. Your component is defined in `checkout_index_index.xml` file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shippingAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">shippingAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="my_element" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/checkout/custom</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create component js file similar to this

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function (ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/checkout/custom',
        },

        initialize: function (config) {
            this.instoreShipping= ko.observable(false);
            return this._super(config);
        },

        setInstoreShipping: function(value) {
            this.instoreShipping(value == true);
        }
    });
});
```

and then in html file

```
<form id="custom-checkout-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="custom-checkbox" id="custom-checkbox" data-bind="change: setInstoreShipping" />
</form>
```